# ASP.net MVC3 Select Foreign Key in Veiw using DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select

First off, sorry for brinning up, yet again, a topic that has been coverd many times before on this site - As much as I try, I just can't get my code to work.

I have the following model classes:

```
public class ProjectsTable {
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public String ProjectName {get; set;}
  ...
  public virtual Manager Manager_Id {get; set;}  // Stores foreign key of Manager
}

public class Manager {
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public String ManagerName {get; set;}
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<ProjectsTable> Projects {get; set;}
}
```

The ProjectsTable Controller class contains the following method to double as a display and edit page:

```
private SynthContext db = new SynthContext();
...

// GET: /ProjectsTable/Parameters/5
public ActionResult Parameters(int id) {
  ProjectsTable projectstable = db.ProjectsTable.Find(id);
  ViewBag.Manager_Id = new SelectList(db.Manager, "ID", "ManagerName");
  return View(projectstable);
}

// POST: /ProjectsTable/Parameters/5
public ActionResult Parameters(ProjectsTable projectstable) {
  if(ModelState.IsValid) {
    db.Entry(projectstable).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Parameters");
  }
  ViewBag.Manager_Id = new SelectList(db.Manager, "ID", "ManagerName");
  return View(projectstable);
}
```

Finally, Parameters.cshtml contains the following code to display the dropdown

```
@model Synth.Models.ProjectsTable
...
<fieldset>
...
  <div class="editor-lable">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Manager_ID)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
    @HTML.DropDownList("Manager_ID", String.Empty)
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Update">
</fieldset>
```

When I test the code, I can navigate to `/ProjectsTable/Parameters/x` without any problem; the drop-down is correctly generated containing a list of the manager names. However, when I click on the "Update" button, the Manager_ID is highlighted in red indicating the change has not registers. I can confirm that the changes have not registered by navigating to `/ProjectsTable/list` where I find no changes have taken effect.

I have tried adding `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model.Manager_ID)`, the result is alway "The value 'x' is invalid", where x is a valid ID value (I have checked it against the database).

I have looked at the generated HTML source and can't see anything wrong there neither.

I have a suspicion that I need to replace `@HTML.DropDownList` with `@HTML.DropDownListFor`, but I can't figure out what parameters it needs in order to get it working.
**EDIT - I have now managed to get `DropDownListFor` working, but the problem persists. A related question to help me resolve this issue might be how to view the post data sent back to the server.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanking you all in advance...

Chopo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the problem. It had nothing to do with the view or the controller. Apparently I hadn't properly written up the model: The foreign key should be stored as an `int?` as well as a pointer to the model in question.

```
public class ProjectsTable {
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public String ProjectName {get; set;}
  ...

  public int? ManagerID {get; set;}  // Stores foreign key of Manager
  public virtual Manager Manager // I have no idea if this line does anything
}

public class Manager {
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public String ManagerName {get; set;}
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<ProjectsTable> Projects {get; set;}
}
```

Whilst not necessary, the View also benefits from using the function:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Manager_ID, ViewBag.Manager_Id as SelectList, String.Empty)
```

The function `@HTML.DropDownList("ManagerID", String.Empty)` also works, but in order for it to do so the name of the ViewBag object being passed from the controller (`ManagerID`) must exactly match the foreign key  of the model. This is convoluted and confusing for my taste. I prefer the strongly typed approach.

For completeness, I include the fully corrected code:

Controller:

```
private SynthContext db = new SynthContext();
...

// GET: /ProjectsTable/Parameters/5
public ActionResult Parameters(int id) {
  ProjectsTable projectstable = db.ProjectsTable.Find(id);
  // The following line has been amended, but this change is not strictly necessary
  ViewBag.m_id = new SelectList(db.Manager, "ID", "ManagerName", projectstable.ManagerID);
  return View(projectstable);
}

// POST: /ProjectsTable/Parameters/5
public ActionResult Parameters(ProjectsTable projectstable) {
  if(ModelState.IsValid) {
    db.Entry(projectstable).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Parameters");
  }
  ViewBag.m_id = new SelectList(db.Manager, "ID", "ManagerName", projectstable.ManagerID);
  return View(projectstable);
}
```

View:

```
@model Synth.Models.ProjectsTable
...
<fieldset>
...
  <div class="editor-lable">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagerID)
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
    Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ManagerID, ViewBag.m_id as SelectList, String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManagerID)
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Update">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing yourself because you have a model property `Manager_Id` and a viewBag object `Manager_Id`.  Your modelState error is referring to the model property, not any of the values in the drop down list, which are bound to the viewBag object.  I suggest re-naming your ViewBag to avoid confusion (or, better yet, not using ViewBag at all), and adding a hidden field for the model property:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Manager_Id)
```

As a side note, from your descriptions of your troubleshooting efforts above, I also suggest becoming comfortable debugging in visual studio, setting breakpoints and inspecting values.  It will make your life so much easier in the long run.

Comment: Interestingly, once I rename the viewbag to `m_id` and change the cshtml code to `@HTML.DropDownList("m_ID", String.Empty)` I no longer get any validation error, but now my controller simply does not register and store what I select in the `DropDownList`. Can I actually use `DropDownList`, or do I need to switch to `DropDownListFor` and if so what parameters do I need to input.

Comment: The documentation for DropDownListFor is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.108).aspx).

Comment: The ddl values aren't in your controller because the viewBag object is not part of the model that you are passing.

Comment: Generally, you are right in your assumption that you should be using the stronly typed helper.  Just search 'Dropdownlistfor'.  There are thousands of how-to's out there.

Comment: Yep, red that, problem is Here is how I interpreted it applied to my code: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Manager_ID, ViewBag.m_id, String.Empty), but when I type that VS gives me the following error `System...ProjectTable has no applicable method named DropDownListFor but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax`. I, just can't descifer this message =(

Comment: "_The ddl values aren't in your controller because the viewBag object is not part of the model that you are passing._" I presume this is why you advised against using the ViewBag in the first place `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Manager_Id)`

Comment: You need to cast your ViewBag object to a Select list for the helper:  `Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Manager_ID, ViewBag.m_id as SelectList, String.Empty)`

Comment: Thanks, that allows me to use the `DropDownListFor`, however, I still get the same problem, the controller sees the drop-down response as invalid. `ValidationMessageFor` returns "The value 'x' is invalid"